# How to write data to .sqlite3 from SelectMultipleField (Flask), many to many relation, SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I can add to database only `title` and `content` fields. But when it comes to adding `categories` from SelectMultipleField, it goes wrong. Now submit button of form (named 'Add') doesn't work when I select one or more items (categories). In practice nothing happens, still I have form with entered data without redirect. Request (in Firefox dev tools) has this elements. But in design, it should redirect to entry page. It works like that when not enter any categories.

view:

```
@app.route('/add_entry', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_entry():
    form = EntryForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        title = request.form.get('title')
        content = request.form.get('content')
        #categories = request.form.get('categories')
        categories_from_form = request.form.getlist('categories')
        categories = [Category(title=title) for title in categories_from_form]

        entry = Entry(title=title, content=content)
        if categories:
            entry.categories = categories
        db.session.add(entry)
        db.session.commit()
        session['entry_id'] = Entry.query.filter_by(title=title).all()[0].id

        return redirect(f'entries/{session.get("entry_id")}')
    return render_template('add_entry.html', form=form)
```

models:

```
entry_category = db.Table('entry_category',
                      db.Column('entry_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('entry.id')),
                      db.Column('category_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
                      )


class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, index=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Category id: {self.id} title: {self.title}>'


class Entry(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, index=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    categories = db.relationship('Category', secondary=entry_category, backref='entries')

    # author = ...
    # editor = ...

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Entry id: {self.id} title: {self.title}, content: {self.content}, ' \
               f'categories: {[i for i in self.categories]}>'
```

form:

```
class EntryForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    content = TextAreaField('Content')
    categories = SelectMultipleField('Category', choices=[i for i in Category.query.all()])
    submit = SubmitField('Add')
```

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}


{% block title %}
{{ super() }} update
{% endblock title %}


{% block content %}

{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
<div class="alert alert-warning">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}


<br><br>
<h1>Add new entry</h1>
<br>

<div class="shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded">
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to retrieve only `title` from form and select objects with this `title` in view.

##### form:

```py
class EntryForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    content = TextAreaField('Content')
    categories = SelectMultipleField('Category', choices=[i.title for i in Category.query.all()])
    submit = SubmitField('Add')
```

##### view:

```py
@app.route('/add_entry', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_entry():
    form = EntryForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        title = request.form.get('title')
        content = request.form.get('content')
        categories_from_form = request.form.getlist('categories')
        categories = [Category.query.filter_by(title=i).first() for i in categories_from_form]
        entry = Entry(title=title, content=content, categories=categories)
        db.session.add(entry)
        db.session.commit()
        session['entry_id'] = Entry.query.filter_by(title=title).all()[0].id

        return redirect(f'entries/{session.get("entry_id")}')
    return render_template('add_entry.html', form=form)
```